# Crontab on shared hosting, not being started

Tags: cron

Alright so I'm having an issue.

I've setup this correctly but something is out of order

I added this to my crontab

```
 * * * * * /home/website/public_html/ && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Now if I start this command from my terminal it will work, but on the crontab log I get this

> /bin/sh: /home/website/public_html/ : is a directory

Answer (score 0):

After the frequency of the execution (in your case five stars to run every minute) crontab syntax expects to find the command to run.
I guess you want change the working directory before running php, so you need to add `cd` to change directory:

```
cd /home/website/public_html/ && php artisan schedule:run
```

Anyway, there is plenty of examples and explanations about crontab in internet.